# How do I sort a GTK treeview with its child different from its parent

Tags: python, sorting, treeview, gtk

I have a GTK TreeView that displays Artist names as its parent node and their associated Albums in the child node i.e. an artist can have many albums

The Artist names in the treeview - treestore model are connected to the TreeView column so that the user can click the column header to sort the Artist names in either an Ascending or Descending order.

However - I need also the child Album names to be in a fixed name order e.g. either Ascending or Descending

For example - for albums in fixed ascending order then when the column header is Ascending:

```
MJ -
   - Album1MJ
   - Album2MJ
PQ -
   - Album1PQ
   - Album2PQ
ZY -
   - Album1ZY
```

When the column header is Descending:

```
ZY -
   - Album1ZY
PQ -
   - Album1PQ
   - Album2PQ
MJ -
   - Album1MJ
   - Album2MJ
```

Thus, using a GtkTreeModelSort on my treeview I have defined a `set_sort_func` on column 0 which is the Artist Name column

The `set_sort_func` is defined as:

```
def _compare(self, model, row1, row2, user_data):
    sort_column = 0

    value1 = model.get_value(row1, sort_column)
    value2 = model.get_value(row2, sort_column)
    if value1 < value2:
        return -1
    elif value1 == value2:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1
```

This sorts the Artist Names.

My question is, how do I apply the sub-sort to ensure the album names are specifically in either an Ascending order or Descending order?

I'm using Gtk3 and the above example is python2.7

---

This is the python code I'm using:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

def _compare(model, row1, row2, user_data):
    sort_column = 0

    value1 = model.get_value(row1, sort_column)
    value2 = model.get_value(row2, sort_column)
    if value1 < value2:
        return -1
    elif value1 == value2:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1

w = Gtk.Window()
w.resize(300, 300)

model = Gtk.TreeStore(str)
model.set_sort_column_id(0, Gtk.SortType.ASCENDING)

artist_iter=model.append(None, ['PQ'])
model.append(artist_iter, ['Album1PQ'])
model.append(artist_iter, ['Album2PQ'])
artist_iter=model.append(None, ['MJ'])
model.append(artist_iter, ['ALBUM1MJ'])
model.append(artist_iter, ['ALBUM2MJ'])
artist_iter=model.append(None, ['ZY'])
model.append(artist_iter, ['ALBUM1ZY'])

tv = Gtk.TreeView(model)
tv.set_headers_clickable(True)

c=0
i=0
renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
col = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(c, renderer)
col.add_attribute(renderer, 'text', i)
col.set_clickable(True)
col.set_sort_column_id(0)
col.set_sort_indicator(True)
tv.append_column(col)

tree_sort = Gtk.TreeModelSort(model=model)            
tree_sort.set_sort_func(0, _compare, None)

tree_sort.set_sort_column_id(0, Gtk.SortType.ASCENDING)
tv.set_model(tree_sort)
tv.expand_all()

w.add(tv)
w.show_all()
w.connect('destroy', lambda _: Gtk.main_quit())
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 1):

if you create your TreeViewColumn with:

```
Gtk.TreeViewColumn.set_sort_column_id(0)
```

It should automatically sort parent and child. Try and let me know. If not, put here your python code.

Ok, i understand what you want. Try this:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

w = Gtk.Window()
w.resize(300, 300)

model = Gtk.TreeStore(str, str)

tv = Gtk.TreeView(model)
tv.set_headers_clickable(True)

renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
col_artist = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(0, renderer)
col_artist.add_attribute(renderer, 'text', 0)
col_artist.set_clickable(True)
col_artist.set_sort_indicator(True)
tv.append_column(col_artist)


renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
col_album = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(1, renderer)
col_album.add_attribute(renderer, 'text', 1)
col_album.set_clickable(False)
tv.append_column(col_album)

artist_iter=model.append(None, ['PQ', ''])
model.append(artist_iter, ['', 'Album1PQ'])
model.append(artist_iter, ['', 'Album2PQ'])
artist_iter=model.append(None, ['MJ', ''])
model.append(artist_iter, ['', 'ALBUM1MJ'])
model.append(artist_iter, ['', 'ALBUM2MJ'])
artist_iter=model.append(None, ['ZY', ''])
model.append(artist_iter, ['', 'ALBUM1ZY'])

col_artist.set_sort_column_id(0)
tv.expand_all()

w.add(tv)
w.show_all()
w.connect('destroy', lambda _: Gtk.main_quit())
Gtk.main()
```

I added one column for the album, i set this not clickable and not sortable.
I set the order to col_artist.
I think is the only way, but i'm not sure.
Let me know.
Bye

Comment: Hi - this is definitely one solution (+1) although it looks odd with the separate column.  For example, you cant use the GtkGridlines to visually link the Artist with the Album.  You can sort the second column if you wrap the model with Gtk.TreeModelSort and use set_sort_column_id(1) on the sorted model.  I would prefer if possible to use the one column from a visual point-of-view.

Comment: I agree with you. I also read some documentation, but didn't find nothig. :-( Are we sure is it possible? Anyway, you gave me an idea for another python exercise! Anyway, having different column could be useful if, for example, you want add album year, song duration, ecc